# Number of days since last activity - SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm trying to count the number of days since the last activity. My data is weekly aggregated. I'm able to do the lag but not able to include the current week.

**Data**:

```
ID       DATE       CHANNEL  VENDOR   ENG
xyz      2022-11-18 EMAIL    ALPHA    1 
xyz      2022-11-25 EMAIL    ALPHA    1 
xyz      2022-12-09 EMAIL    ALPHA    1 
xyz      2022-12-16 EMAIL    ALPHA    0 
xyz      2022-12-23 EMAIL    ALPHA    0
xyz      2022-12-30 EMAIL    ALPHA    3
```

I would like to have the output to be as follows:

```
ID       DATE       CHANNEL  VENDOR   ENG   n_days
xyz      2022-11-18 EMAIL    ALPHA    1     0
xyz      2022-11-25 EMAIL    ALPHA    1     0
xyz      2022-12-09 EMAIL    ALPHA    1     0
xyz      2022-12-16 EMAIL    ALPHA    0     7
xyz      2022-12-23 EMAIL    ALPHA    0     14
xyz      2022-12-30 EMAIL    ALPHA    3     0
```

I have written a query but it not able to include the most latest week. Below is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, DATE, CHANNEL, VENDOR,
     DATE - LAG(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, CHANNEL, VENDOR ORDER BY DATE) AS "NDAYS_LAST_ENGAGED_CHANNEL_VENDOR"
FROM 
   tab1
WHERE 
   ENG>0
```

Comment: Please **check** the tags used on your question!   MySQL and SQL-Server are incompatible, specify only the one that you are using.

Comment: Sorry, about that. Just wanted to get my questions in front of more people. Query mostly remains the same isn't it?

Comment: Still specify the dbms you're using here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to construct a right query that would give difference in days since last event in a chronological order with a massive help of James Casey. The query is as below:

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.DATE, T1.CHANNEL, T1.VENDOR,
       IFNULL(MIN(DATEDIFF(DD, T_ENG.EVENT_DATE, T1.EVENT_DATE)), -1) AS "N_DAYS"
FROM
  TAB1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TAB1 AS T_ENG 
        ON T_ENG.ENG>0 AND T1.ID=T_ENG.ID AND T1.CHANNEL=T_ENG.CHANNEL AND T1.VENDOR=T_ENG.VENDOR
            AND DATEDIFF(DD, T_ENG.DATE, T1.DATE)>=0
GROUP BY
    T1.ID, T1.DATE, T1.CHANNEL, T1.VENDOR
ORDER BY 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause means it will only output the rows where eng > 0, so there is no way it will return what you want - its going to throw the last two rows away. And LAG will be just refer to the previous row in the partition, its not going to search for a row that matches your where clause as I think you hoped.

This should hopefully put you on the right track. I've assumed Sql server, though :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t
CREATE TABLE #t (ID VARCHAR(3), [DATE] DATE, CHANNEL VARCHAR(5), VENDOR VARCHAR(5), ENG INT);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES 
('xyz','20221118','EMAIL','ALPHA',1), 
('xyz','20221125','EMAIL','ALPHA',0), 
('xyz','20221209','EMAIL','ALPHA',1), 
('xyz','20221216','EMAIL','ALPHA',0), 
('xyz','20221223','EMAIL','ALPHA',0);


SELECT t1.ID, t1.DATE, t1.CHANNEL, t1.VENDOR, t1.ENG,
    MIN(CASE WHEN t1.ENG = 0 
        THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t_eng.DATE, t1.DATE)
        ELSE 0
    END) AS N_DAYS
FROM #t t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #t t_eng ON t_eng.ENG = 1
    AND t_eng.CHANNEL = t1.CHANNEL
    AND t_eng.ID = t1.ID 
    AND t_eng.VENDOR = t1.VENDOR    
    AND t_eng.DATE < t1.DATE
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.DATE, t1.CHANNEL, t1.VENDOR, t1.ENG
```

Comment: The Max don't work when I another have ENG<>0 after ENG=0. It results in negative days. I was hoping there was a way to do it using some kind of a window function

Comment: Okay I have changed it to handle multiple gaps. If this is not what you mean, update your data and expected output in your question to include some examples of what you need

Comment: Also its going to give NULL if there is a 0 Eng with no earlier 1 Eng row, you could use ISNULL to provide a default value

Comment: Thanks James, your answer is not quite what I was looking for but it definitely helped construct a right query. My data is ordered chronologically on DATE and for the earlier months your query would still give negative days. I guess I could provide a better representation but anyway, thanks a lot, I'm answering my own question which is inspired from your answer so thank you.